# Symfony2 project with VirtualHost doesn't work

Tags: symfony, virtualhost, symfony-2.3

I'm working on a Symfony2 project (using latest 2.3.2) and for that I made this virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/nnplat/web
    ServerName nnplat.devserver

    <Directory /var/www/html/nnplat/web>
       AllowOverride all
       Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog logs/nnplat-error_log
    CustomLog logs/nnplat-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

If I call `http://nnplat.devserver` I got this error:

> Oops! An Error Occurred The server returned a "404 Not Found".
>   Something is broken. Please e-mail us at [email] and let us know what
>   you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as
>   possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.

But if I call this URL `http://devserver/nnplat/web/app_dev.php` it works, where is the problem? I can't find what is wrong in my VH

Comment: Do you have `DirectoryIndex` set?  Have you checked `http://nnplat.devserver/app_dev.php`?

Comment: @vinodadhikary no in the sample code but yes already tried with `DirectoryIndex app.php` and results are the same also checked the `app_dev.php` and nothing `404 error found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
ServerName nnplat.devserver
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/nnplat/web
<Directory "/var/www/html/nnplat/web">
DirectoryIndex app_dev.php
Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch
AllowOverride All
Allow from All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: nothing, get the same error and `ServerName` should go inside the Virtual Host definition since I've some others VH in there